# How to create a polyvariadic haskell function?

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions, function-parameter, polyvariadic

I need a function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments (All of the same type), does something with them and afterwards gives a result back. A list of arguments is impracticable in my specific case.

As I looked through the haskell libs, I saw that the function `printf` (from module `Text.Printf`) uses a similar trick. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand that magic by looking at the source.

Can somebody explain how to achieve this, or at least some webpage/paper/whatever where I could find a good description for this?

**Motivation:**

The reason I need this is really quite simple. For school (computer science class), we are required to write a module that is able to "record" a mathematical expression, express it as a string (Via writing an instance of Num/Real/etc for an own datatype), and perform various operations on it.

This datatype contains a special constructor for a variable, which may be replaced by a value or whatever by a specified function. One of the goals is to write a function, which takes such an expression with some number of variables (pairs of type `(Char,Rational)`) and calculates the result of the expression. We should look at how to express the goal of the function best. (My idea: The function returns another function which takes exactly as many arguments as vars that are defined in the function - seems to be impossible).

Comment: It would be interesting to see your use case for this.

Comment: Just some project for school. I'll edit the question and post the purpose.

Comment: You might consider other approaches - a function taking a list: evaluate :: [(Char, Rational)] -> Expr -> Rational; a function taking a function: (Char -> Rational) -> Expr -> Rational; a function taking a map: Data.Map.Map Char Rational -> Expr -> Rational.

Comment: Note that using such a variadic function means that users of your module will receive very cryptic error messages when their code doesn't type-check. It's much easier to understand an error like "this is not a list" than an error like "missing instance of PrintfType ... for ...".

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The key points of `printf` is the ability to either return a String or a function. Copied from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/src/Text-Printf.html,

```
printf :: (PrintfType r) => String -> r
printf fmts = spr fmts []

class PrintfType t where
    spr :: String -> [UPrintf] -> t

instance (IsChar c) => PrintfType [c] where
    spr fmts args = map fromChar (uprintf fmts (reverse args))

instance (PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r) where
    spr fmts args = \a -> spr fmts (toUPrintf a : args)
```

and the basic structure we can extract out is

```
variadicFunction :: VariadicReturnClass r => RequiredArgs -> r
variadicFunction reqArgs = variadicImpl reqArgs mempty

class VariadicReturnClass r where
   variadicImpl :: RequiredArgs -> AccumulatingType -> r

instance VariadicReturnClass ActualReturnType where
   variadicImpl reqArgs acc = constructActualResult reqArgs acc

instance (ArgClass a, VariadicReturnClass r) => VariadicReturnClass (a -> r) where
   variadicImpl reqArgs acc = \a -> variadicImpl reqArgs (specialize a `mappend` acc)
```

For instance:

```
class SumRes r where 
    sumOf :: Integer -> r

instance SumRes Integer where
    sumOf = id

instance (Integral a, SumRes r) => SumRes (a -> r) where
    sumOf x = sumOf . (x +) . toInteger
```

then we could use

```
*Main> sumOf 1 :: Integer
1
*Main> sumOf 1 4 7 10 :: Integer
22
*Main> sumOf 1 4 7 10 0 0  :: Integer
22
*Main> sumOf 1 4 7 10 2 5 8 22 :: Integer
59
```

Comment: @KennyTM: Do you know, whether there is a tag for polyvariadic functions?

Comment: @FUZxxl: On this site? There is one for [variadic-functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-functions) but it is C/C++-centric.

Comment: Hm... AFAIK (poly)variadic functions are a big topic in haskell programming. I don't no the guidelines, but maybe just create a tag for this purpose. (Or should I use variadic-functions)?

Comment: @FUZxxl: If it is distinct enough from variadic functions of C, create a new tag.

Comment: I haven't the required reputation to create a new tag.

Comment: It actually is far away from C-style polyvariadic stuff, because in C they`re unsafe, threaten as a list and builtin, in Haskell they are rather a programming technique than a real language feature, and also extremely different in their handling.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Added [polyvariadic] in, together with [variadic-functions].

Comment: In C it's unsafe (but then the language is, as a whole), but in C++0x variadic templates allow for type safe polyvariadic functions.

Comment: nice! your first sentence explain all!

Comment: How does Haskell know which of the instances to use? The one that returns the integer or the one that returns a function? Is it because of the `:: Integer` you tacked on the end?

Comment: What kind of type inference algorithm allows one to ask for the result type to specify the input type? It sounds kind of like a logic language feature.

Comment: I noticed that this kind of works without the `:: Integer` in GHCI. Of course the type returned is weird. However I changed your implementation to append strings instead, and I had to use 2 language pragmas (TypeSynonymInstances and FlexibleInstances), but in that case, I needed `:: String` or GHCI complains about ambiguous instances. So how come integers don't come with ambiguous instances?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `Integer` gets chosen by GHCi's [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) mechanism, as the first type in the list `(), Integer, Double` which has all the instances needed. In files normally ordinary numeric defaulting is used, which has stricter requirements and so doesn't trigger here.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai W.r.t. your older comment: Haskell type inference uses unification, which is also used by logic languages like Prolog. So yes, definitely related.

Comment: Would the solution to applying a list of arguments to a polyvariadic function be to recursively apply the function while iterating over the list?

Comment: @kennytm Why did you call the class `SumRes`?

Comment: @FtheBuilder Summation Result. The class name isn't important, though.

Comment: I tried using Int instead of Integer and `instance (SumRes r) => SumRes (Int -> r) where`,  I managed to compile (I had to set `XFlexibleInstances` flag), but when I try to run it, I have to use `sumOf (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int) :: Int`... Ok, maybe it's a silly comment, but I can't understand clearly what is going on. Why can't Haskell infer the type in this case?

Comment: @FtheBuilder Perhaps you could [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but I guess it is related to the FlexibleInstances, and that a number is not a concrete type but a `Num a => a`.

Answer (score 11):

KennyTM's answer is great. Below is an example of the exec process of `sumOf 1 4 7 10 :: Integer` to give a better illustration.

```
sumOf 1 4 7 10
(( \ x -> ( sumOf . (x +) . toInteger ) 1 ) 4 7 10
((sumOf . (1 + ) . toInteger) 4 ) 7 10
( sumOf 5 ) 7 10
( sumOf . (5 + ) . toInteger ) 7 10
sumOf 12 10
sumOf . (12 + ) . toInteger 10
sumof 22
id 22
22
```

Answer (score 10):

Lots of people are telling you how to create variadic functions, but I think in this case you're actually better off just using a list of type [(Char,Rational)].

Comment: Please look, delnan has said exactly this.  
Yes, I know, that this would be easier, but it's very usefull to understand, how such mechanics works by implementing it in an own program.

Comment: Also something to note: This is the *idiomatic* way to write it as well.  The only variadic function that I think I've used is `printf`; I'd expect your function to take a list.

Comment: The only other sensible usage of a variadic function I can think of (except `printf`) would be designing a DSL for which there is such a specific requirement.

Answer (score 7):

In the wiki article on variadic functions, [this article](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/polyvariadic.html#polyvar-fn) was referenced. I suppose this is what printf does, but I don't understand it either. Anyway, this is *certainly* an overkill, especially since your arguments are all of the same type. Just put them all in one list. That's what lists are good for - an arbitary number of things of the same type. Fine, it's not very beautiful, but it will hardly be uglier than a complete polyvariadic function.

Comment: Although this is a bit confusing, this seems to be that, what I need.

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at [an example](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/vararg-fn.lhs) linked from the article that delnan referenced. After staring at it for a bit, I think I finally comprehend what is going on:

It starts with this type class:

```
class BuildList a r  | r-> a where
    build' :: [a] -> a -> r
```

That bit after the pipe (|) is a functional dependency. It says that the type represented by `a` can be determined by the type represented by `r`. In other words, you are prevented from defining two instances of the `BuildList` typeclass with the same `r` (return type), but different `a`.

Jumping ahead a bit to where the `build'` function is actually used:

```
> build True :: [Bool]
```

Since `build` is just calling `build'` with an empty list as the first parameter, this is the same as:

```
> build' [] True :: [Bool]
```

In this example, `build'` is clearly returning a list. Because of the functional dependency, we can only be binding to this instance of the `BuildList` type class:

```
instance BuildList a [a] where
    build' l x = reverse$ x:l
```

Pretty straightforward. The second example is more interesting. Expanding the definition of `build`, it becomes:

```
> build' [] True False :: [Bool]
```

What's the type of `build'` in this case? Well, the precedence rules of Haskell mean that the above could also be written like this:

```
> (build' [] True) False :: [Bool]
```

Now it becomes clear that we are passing two parameters to `build'` and then applying the result of that expression to a parameter with value 'False'. In other words, the expression `(build' [] True)` is expected to return a *function* of type `Bool -> [Bool]`. And that binds us to the second instance of the `BuildList` typeclass:

```
instance BuildList a r => BuildList a (a->r) where
    build' l x y = build'(x:l) y
```

In this invocation, `l = []` and `x = True` and `y = False`, so the definition expands to `build' [True] False :: [Bool]`. That signature binds to the first instance of `build'`, and it's fairly obvious where it goes from there.

Comment: This description is extremely straightforward and very usefull. The only thing which remains unclear for me is that definition `build' l x = reverse $ x:l`.  
But in my opinion, the answer of KennyTM is more usefull, because I rather want to iterate over the parameters than having them presented as a list.