# How can I transform a list of values to a data constructor's parameters?

Tags: haskell

I am processing a web request, and trying to save a potential entity (User / Address 1). The main question is, how can I transform a list of Strings to parameters to a function - where the list could be of arbitrary length.

I have looked at [Passing list elements as parameters to curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775446/passing-list-elements-as-parameters-to-curried-function) but this seems to be a solution only when knowing the amount of parameters in advance.

---

```
data User = User String String
data Address1 = Address1 String

let ufields = ["chris", "str"]
let afields = ["earth"]
```

I'm looking for a function along the lines of:

```
f :: [String] -> (? -> c) -> Maybe c
f fields c = undefined
```

So all I would need to pass is the data constructor (User/Address1), and a list of strings.

Examples:

`f ufields User` would return `Just ( User "chris" "str")`.

`f ["chris"] User` would return `Nothing`.

`f [] User` would return `Nothing`.

`f afields Address1` would return `Just ( Address1 "earth" )`.

Is this possible to be done without using TemplateHaskell? I can achieve the above manually, but it involves quite a bit of additional typing:

```
data User = User String String deriving (Show)
data Address1 = Address1 String deriving (Show)

data EntityType = UserEntity | AddressEntity
data EntityContainer = UserContainer User | AddressContainer Address1

f :: EntityType -> [String] -> Maybe EntityContainer
f UserEntity  (p:p':[]) = Just $ UserContainer $ User p p'
f AddressEntity  (p:[]) = Just $ AddressContainer $ Address1 p
f _ _ = Nothing

printPossibleEntity :: [String] -> EntityType -> IO ()
printPossibleEntity fields entityType = 
  case (f entityType fields) of
    Just (UserContainer u) -> print u
    Just (AddressContainer a) -> print a
    Nothing -> print "No entity matched"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let ufields = ["chris", "str"]
  let afields = ["earth"]
  printPossibleEntity ufields UserEntity
  printPossibleEntity afields AddressEntity
  printPossibleEntity [] AddressEntity
```

Which outputs:

```
User "chris" "str"
Address1 "earth"
"No entity matched"
```

Comment: Why do you need to abstract over the constructor? How are you going to use the return value of `f` if you don't know its type ahead of time?

Comment: I would create a typeclass where `User` would have a instance relating to this. So `save (User "chris" "str")` would work as an example.

Comment: This seems like a poor design. Rather than try to create one function which does all of the work, you should create several smaller, simpler functions which each deal with a different entity type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that you should almost certainly *not* use this.

The usual way of doing this sort of thing is to have overlapping multiparameter typeclasses.

### First attempt

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances,
             UndecidableInstances #-}

class PackArgs a b | a -> b where
  packArgs :: [String] -> a -> Maybe b

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} PackArgs y z => PackArgs (String -> y) z where
  packArgs [] _ = Nothing
  packArgs (a:as) f = packArgs as (f a)

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} PackArgs z z where
  packArgs (_:_) _ = Nothing
  packArgs [] z = Just z
```

And here it is working in action:

```
ghci> data User = User String String deriving Show
ghci> data Address1 = Address1 String deriving Show
ghci> packArgs ["chris","str"] User :: Maybe User
Just (User "chris" "str")
ghci> packArgs ["chris"] User :: Maybe User
Nothing
ghci> packArgs [] User :: Maybe User
Nothing
ghci> packArgs ["earth"] Address1 :: Maybe Address1
Just (Address1 "earth")
```

The problem is that we need the type annotations for this to work. In a nutshell, Haskell needs to know what your expected return type is. We can fix this with some type families.

### Second attempt

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances,
             UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Proxy

type family StringFuncReturn a where
  StringFuncReturn (String -> b) = StringFuncReturn b
  StringFuncReturn b = b

class PackArgs a where
  packArgs :: [String] -> a -> Maybe (StringFuncReturn a)

instance (StringFuncReturn a ~ r, PackArgs' a r) => PackArgs a where
  packArgs = packArgs' (Proxy :: Proxy r)

class PackArgs' a b where
  packArgs' :: Proxy b -> [String] -> a -> Maybe b

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} PackArgs' y z => PackArgs' (String -> y) z where
  packArgs' _ [] _ = Nothing
  packArgs' p (a:as) f = packArgs' p as (f a)

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} PackArgs' z z where
  packArgs' _ (_:_) _ = Nothing
  packArgs' _ [] z = Just z
```

And here it is working in action:

```
ghci> data User = User String String deriving Show
ghci> data Address1 = Address1 String deriving Show
ghci> packArgs ["chris","str"] User
Just (User "chris" "str")
ghci> packArgs ["chris"] User
Nothing
ghci> packArgs [] User
Nothing
ghci> packArgs ["earth"] Address1
Just (Address1 "earth")
```