# Haskell function that takes a variadic function as an argument (and returns something else than that func) without FlexibleInstances, pure Haskell2010

Tags: haskell, types, lambda, typeclass, variadic-functions

is it possible to express the following Haskell program *without FlexibleInstances*, i.e. in pure Haskell2010?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class    Funk a       where  truth :: a  -> [Bool]
instance Funk [Bool]  where  truth =  \x ->  x
instance Funk Bool    where  truth =  \x -> [x]

instance Funk b => Funk (Bool -> b) where
    truth f = concat [truth (f True), truth (f False)]
```

This is inspired by the answer on [How to write a Haskell function that takes a variadic function as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353845/how-to-write-a-haskell-function-that-takes-a-variadic-function-as-an-argument).

I suspect the problem is, that `truth` returns something else than the function which it takes as an argument (which returns `Bool`, not `[Bool]`).

The purpose of this snippet is, to give a list of all evaluations of all possible configuration for a boolean function, i.e.

```
Main> truth (\x y -> x && y)
[True,False,False,False]

Main> truth (\x y -> x || y)
[True,True,True,False]
```

In the end, a truth-table is to be printed, like this (see boiler-plate at the end of this post to see the code which produces this):

```
Main> main
T T T | T
T T F | T
T F T | T
T F F | F
F T T | T
F T F | F
F F T | T
F F F | T
```

Here is some boiler-plate code for testing and visualizing, what the purpose of this function is:

```
class TruthTable a where
    truthTable :: Funk f => f -> a

instance TruthTable [String] where
    truthTable f = zipWith (++) (hCells (div (length t) 2)) (map showBool $ truth f)
        where
            showBool True = "| T"
            showBool False = "| F"
            hCells 1 = ["T ", "F "]
            hCells n = ["T " ++ x | x <- hCells (div n 2)] ++ ["F " ++ x | x <- hCells (div n 2)]

instance TruthTable [Char] where
    truthTable f = foldl1 join (truthTable f)
        where join a b = a ++ "\n" ++ b

instance TruthTable (IO a) where
    truthTable f = putStrLn (truthTable f) >> return undefined

main :: IO ()
main = truthTable (\x y z -> x `xor` y ==> z)

xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor a b = not $ a == b

(==>) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
a ==> b = not $ a && not b
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No problem:

```
class    Funk a                  where  truth :: a  -> [Bool]
instance (IsBool a) => Funk [a]  where  truth =  map toBool
instance Funk Bool               where  truth =  \x -> [x]

instance (IsBool a, Funk b) => Funk (a -> b) where
    truth f = concat [truth (f $ fromBool True), truth (f $ fromBool False)]

class IsBool a where
    toBool :: a -> Bool
    fromBool :: Bool -> a

instance IsBool Bool where
    toBool = id
    fromBool = id
```

You can even make 'honorary booleans' if you wish, like Integer with 0 and 1 etc.

Comment: Aah, thanks. I've seen a similar “trick” with IsChar in Text.Printf... darn!

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell98 way is to use newtypes for ([] Bool) and ((->) Bool b):

```
newtype LB = LB [Bool]
newtype FAB b = FAB (Bool -> b)

class    Funk a       where  truth :: a  -> [Bool]
instance Funk LB      where  truth =  \(LB x) -> x
instance Funk Bool    where  truth =  \x -> [x]

instance Funk b => Funk (FAB b) where
    truth (FAB f) = concat [truth (f True), truth (f False)]
```

This part then compiles without needed any LANGUAGE extensions.  But it eliminates the use case of making 'truth' simple to work with.

Comment: To be clear to other readers, FlexibleInstances is a safe extension to the type system.  Documentation for GHC is at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules

Comment: I asked this exact thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367423/are-haskell-flexibleinstances-a-stable-extension-to-the-language, however I was interested in a solution without extensions.