# Haskell Variadic Function & Instance Declarations

Tags: haskell, types

I was attempting to understand the example given at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467279/how-to-create-a-polyvariadic-haskell-function) about variadic functions and tried to modify the code from:

```
class SumRes r where 
    sumOf :: Integer -> r

instance SumRes Integer where
    sumOf = id

instance (Integral a, SumRes r) => SumRes (a -> r) where
    sumOf x = sumOf . (x +) . toInteger
```

to this:

```
class SumRes r where 
    sumOf :: Int -> r

instance SumRes Int where
    sumOf = id

instance (SumRes r) => SumRes (Int -> r) where
    sumOf x = sumOf . (x +)
```

I get a `Illegal instance declaration for SumRes (Int -> r)`. Can someone explain what this means and what is the constraint I'm against?

Comment: Just add a `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` pragma on top of the file and it'll compile fine

Comment: But what is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleInstances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just running into the limits of the Haskell standard. Standard Haskell only permits a [restricted set of instance declarations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.2). In particular all instances have to be "simple" in the sense that they're a type applied to zero or more *type variables*.

This means you can have instances for `Int`, `Maybe` or `Maybe a`. However, you *cannot* have an instance for something like `Maybe Int`. That's the problem you're running into here: your instance has a type (`->`) applied to `Int` as well as a variable.

However, despite the fact that this behavior isn't in the standard, it still makes sense, so you can enable it with an extension. That's what `FlexibleInstances` does, with the obvious caveat that your code is not standard Haskell any more.

Answer (score 3):

In standard Haskell, instance heads (the part after the class name in an instance) are required to be of the form `T a1 a2 .. an` where `T` is a type constructor and the `ai` are distinct type variables.

The compiler complains because your instance head is `(->) Int r`, and `Int` is not a type variable.

In GHC, this restriction can be lifted using the `FlexibleInstances` extension, and the only real downside to doing so is a possible lack of portability.