# Functional dependencies in a particular case

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

As an introduction, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973648/use-contents-of-a-list-as-positional-arguments-to-a-single-multi-argument-functi) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26977705/1019245). I note at the end that it seems that you could remove the need for extraneous type specification with a functional dependency. Here is the code as it stands:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

data Nil
data TList a b where
    TEmpty :: TList Nil Nil
    (:.) :: c -> TList d e -> TList c (TList d e)
infixr 4 :.

class TApplies f h t r where
    tApply :: f -> TList h t -> r

instance TApplies a Nil Nil a where
    tApply a _ = a

instance TApplies f h t r => TApplies (a -> f) a (TList h t) r where
    tApply f (e :. l) = tApply (f e) l]
```

Now, the intuitive thing for me to do seems to be to add the fundep `f h t -> r` to the 
`TApplies` typeclass. However, when I do this, GHC complains about the recursive instance of `TApplies` as follows:

```
Illegal instance declaration for
‘TApplies (a -> f) a (TList h t) r’
The coverage condition fails in class ‘TApplies’
   for functional dependency: ‘f h t -> r’
Reason: lhs types ‘a -> f’, ‘a’, ‘TList h t’
   do not jointly determine rhs type ‘r’
```

The last two lines seem wrong to me, although I expect I simply misunderstand something. My reasoning is as follows:

1. If we have `a -> f` and `a`, then we have `f`.
2. If we have `TList h t` then we have `h` and `t`.
3. Since we have `TApplies f h t r`, we have the fundep `f h t -> r`.
4. Therefore, because we have `f`, `h` and `t`, we have `r`.

This implies to me that the functional dependency *is* satified. Can someone point out the flaw in my logic, and also perhaps suggest a more apt choice of functional dependency? (Note that something like `f r -> h` is permitted by GHC but does not seem to provide much leeway in type indication.)

Comment: The `r` parameter actually seems pretty superfluous to me - if all `TLists` end in a `TList Nil Nil` then `f ~ r` is always true, isn't it?

Comment: Nevermind. I wrote what you're trying to do in terms that I'm more familiar with, and I now understand what you're trying to do - and run into the same issue. I'll see if I can't find a solution, or an explanation, or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I have no idea why you are using such a complicated datatype - so I'll use a simplified one to address your question. The same principle applies to your exact scenario, however.

Define the datatype simple as:

```
data TList (xs :: [*]) where 
  Nil :: TList '[]
  (:.) :: x -> TList xs -> TList (x ': xs) 

infixr 4 :.
```

Then your class has one less type parameter:

```
class TApplies f (xs :: [*]) r | f xs -> r where ...
```

and the problematic instance would look like

```
instance TApplies g ys q => TApplies (y -> g) (y ': ys) q where
```

Now, examine the error this produces (it is essentially the same as in your question) - namely, note that it says "The coverage condition fails in class `TApplies'". So what is this "Coverage condition"? The [user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-termination-rules) has this to say:

> The Coverage Condition. For each functional dependency, tvsleft ->
>   tvsright, of the class, every type variable in S(tvsright) must appear
>   in S(tvsleft), where S is the substitution mapping each type variable
>   in the class declaration to the corresponding type in the instance
>   declaration.

This is overly technical, but basically it says that the set of type variables in the right hand side - in this case, that is `{q}`, must be a subset of the set of variables in the left hand side - here `{y, g, ys}`. This is obviously not the case.

You will notice that the coverage condition says nothing about the context of the instance. This is the root of your problem! The context is *not* considered when deciding if the functional dependency holds. I think you would agree with me that it obviously fails for the instance `instance TApplies (y -> g) (y ': ys) q where ...`, which is what the compiler sees.

The solution is simple: add `{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}` to the top of your file. The purpose of the coverage condition, among other things, is to ensure instance resolution is terminating. If you enable `UndecidableInstances`, you are saying "trust me, it terminates".

---

As a side note, the current formulation is not very nice to use. For example, `tApply (+) (1 :. 2 :. Nil)` produces an "ambiguous type" error, or something of the sort. Even worse, `tApply (+) (1 :. "s" :. Nil)` produces the same exact "ambiguous type" error! Not very helpful for anyone trying to write code with this class. You would have to specify monomorphic type signatures everywhere to get it to work as-is.

The solution is to chance the instance declarations to the following:

```
instance (a ~ a') => TApplies a '[] a' where
instance (TApplies g ys q, y ~ y') => TApplies (y -> g) (y' ': ys) q where
```

Then, the first case compiles as is, type defaulting kicks in, and prints "3". In the second case, you get `No instance for (Num [Char])`, which is actually helpful.

The reason this works is, again, that instance resolution only cares about the instance head, not the context. `instance TApplies (y -> g) (y' ': ys) q` is what the compiler sees, and obviously `y` and `y'` can be any, unrelated, types. It is only at the end, when it is time to print the value, that the compiler needs to resolve the `y ~ y'` constraint, at which point you simply have the expression `(+) 1 2`.

---

You can implement your type without data kinds as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Cons a b 
data Nil

data TList xs where
  Nil  :: TList Nil
  (:.) :: x -> TList xs -> TList (Cons x xs)
```

There is no real reason to do this, however, since DataKinds cannot break otherwise working code.

Comment: I assume your simpler datatype makes use of ``DataKinds``? The reason I didn't use such an approach is because I'm not entirely familiar with that particular language extension. Otherwise: your explanation makes sense, thank you. I'm a bit apprehensive about enabling ``UndecidableInstances`` as it seems that it could go wrong very easily. As a last question, is there a good reason why the context isn't considered when deciding whether the fundep holds?

Comment: Even without data kinds your definition is needlessly complex since it has two type parameters. I'm not certain about this, but I think the context isn't considered in instance selection for the sake of simplicity - implementing a type checker which is coherent and does do so is very non-trivial. The worst thing that can go wrong by enabling UndecidableInstances is the compiler goes into an infinite loop and spits out a "context stack overflow" error after a few seconds.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'm still not entirely certain on how to have only one type parameter without using ``DataKinds``... I'll have a think.

Comment: @JoshKirklin I added that to the answer.