# How to write this polyvariadic composition function in Haskell?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, variadic-functions, function-composition

**Note:** This is a repost of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48539082/783743), which the author deleted. Here's the original question:

---

I have this polyvariadic `comp` function in Javascript and was wondering if a similar implementation in Haskell were possible. I am mostly interested in `comp`'s type:

```
const comp = f => Object.assign(
  g => comp([g].concat(f)),
  {run: x => f.reduce((acc, h) => h(acc), x)}
);

const inc = n => n + 1;
const sqr = n => n * n;
const repeatStr = s => n => Array(n + 1).join(s);

comp(repeatStr("*")) (inc) (sqr).run(2); // "*****"

comp(repeatStr("*"))
  (inc)
  (inc)
  (inc)
  (inc)
  (inc).run(0); // "*****"
```

`comp` builds up a heterogeneous array that usually doesn't have a type in Haskell. I guess such a variadic function must be polymorphic in its return type. However, this task exceeds my Haskell knowledge by far. Any clue would be helpful.

**Context**

I use a Javascript runtime type checker so that I can build up the array inside `comp` in a type-safe manner. It requires explicit type annotations and supports only parametric and rank-2 polymorphism.

Comment: Yeah, that was me. Sorry for deleting it!

Comment: That's alright. If you want to, you could undelete your question and I'll post my answer there. After that, I can delete this question.

Comment: @ftor I wanted to share `const comp = run => Object.assign(g => comp(x => g(run(x))), {run})`

Comment: For others that are interested, this function is a derivative of a fun forward composition toy I made in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918344/633183)

Comment: @naomik I tried to get rid of the array and replace it with a purely functional computation. I really did. But I didn't recognize the pattern. And it was right in front of me! I just have the urgent feeling of learning.

Comment: @ftor you still did a really good job – it's really clever how the input array is built. I took a swing at [variadic comp](https://repl.it/@nakyoto/variadic-comp) and [variadic comp 2](https://repl.it/@nakyoto/variadic-comp-2) which is self-aware. I still think [fwd](https://repl.it/@nakyoto/forward-composition) makes more sense because `comp (f) (g) (h) .run (x)` isn't much better than `vcomp (f,g,h) (x)` – `comp (f) (g) (h)` and `vcomp (f, g, h)` are already independent of `x`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right. You can't build a heterogeneous list of composable functions in Haskell<sup>(1)</sup>. However, you can create your own list data type for composable functions as follows:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Comp a b where
    Id   :: Comp a a
    Comp :: Comp b c -> (a -> b) -> Comp a c

run :: Comp a b -> a -> b
run Id         = id
run (Comp g f) = run g . f
```

The `Id` constructor is similar to `[]` and the `Comp` constructor is similar to `:` but with the arguments flipped.

Next, we use the [varargs pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467279/how-to-create-a-polyvariadic-haskell-function) to create a polyvariadic function. To do so, we define a type class:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Chain a b c | c -> a where
    chain :: Comp a b -> c
```

Note that our state is `Comp b c` and our result is either `Comp b c` or a function that takes another function `(a -> b)` as an input and composes it with our state to produce a new `Chain` called `r` with state `Comp a c`. Let's define instances for these now:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance c ~ c' => Chain b c (Comp b c') where
    chain = id

instance Chain a c r => Chain b c ((a -> b) -> r) where
    chain g f = chain (Comp g f)

comp :: Chain b b c => c
comp = chain Id
```

The `comp` function can now be defined as `chain Id` (i.e. the chain with the empty list `Id` as its state). We can finally use this `comp` function as we'd do in JavaScript:

```hs
inc :: Int -> Int
inc = (+1)

sqr :: Int -> Int
sqr x = x * x

repeatStr :: String -> Int -> String
repeatStr s x = concat (replicate x s)

example1 :: String
example1 = comp (repeatStr "*") inc sqr `run` 2

example2 :: String
example2 = comp (repeatStr "*") inc inc inc inc inc `run` 0
```

Putting it all together:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
             FlexibleInstances #-}

data Comp a b where
    Id   :: Comp a a
    Comp :: Comp b c -> (a -> b) -> Comp a c

run :: Comp a b -> a -> b
run Id         = id
run (Comp g f) = run g . f

class Chain a b c | c -> a where
    chain :: Comp a b -> c

instance c ~ c' => Chain b c (Comp b c') where
    chain = id

instance Chain a c r => Chain b c ((a -> b) -> r) where
    chain g f = chain (Comp g f)

comp :: Chain b b c => c
comp = chain Id

inc :: Int -> Int
inc = (+1)

sqr :: Int -> Int
sqr x = x * x

repeatStr :: String -> Int -> String
repeatStr s x = concat (replicate x s)

example1 :: String
example1 = comp (repeatStr "*") inc sqr `run` 2

example2 :: String
example2 = comp (repeatStr "*") inc inc inc inc inc `run` 0
```

As you can see, the type of `comp` is `Chain b b c => c`. To define the `Chain` type class we require `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`. To use it we require `FlexibleInstances`. Hence, you'll need a sophisticated JavaScript runtime type checker in order to correctly type check `comp`.

---

**Edit:** As [naomik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544123/how-to-write-this-polyvariadic-composition-function-in-haskell#comment84095169_48544123) and [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544123/how-to-write-this-polyvariadic-composition-function-in-haskell#comment84100323_48544124) pointed out in the comments, you can use an actual function instead of a list of composable functions as your internal representation for the state of `comp`. For example, in JavaScript:

```js
const comp = run => Object.assign(g => comp(x => g(run(x))), {run});
```

Similarly, in Haskell:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
             FlexibleInstances #-}

newtype Comp a b = Comp { run :: a -> b }

class Chain a b c | c -> a where
    chain :: Comp a b -> c

instance c ~ c' => Chain b c (Comp b c') where
    chain = id

instance Chain a c r => Chain b c ((a -> b) -> r) where
    chain g f = chain (Comp (run g . f))

comp :: Chain b b c => c
comp = chain (Comp id)
```

Note that even though we don't use GADTs anymore we still require the `GADTs` language extension in order to use the equality constraint `c ~ c'` in the first instance of `Chain`. Also, as you can see `run g . f` has been moved from the definition of `run` into the second instance of `Chain`. Similarly, `id` has been moved from the definition of `run` into the definition of `comp`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> You can use existential types to create a list of heterogeneous functions in Haskell but they won't have the additional constraint of being composable.

Comment: thoughtful and detailed answer, Aadit. Very nice!

Comment: your approach is way more elegant than https://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-dotdotdot-0.1.0.1/docs/Control-DotDotDot.html (even you need `run` at the end) good job!

Comment: The whole development can also be done without GADTs with `newtype Comp a b = Comp { run :: a -> b }`. The `Comp` type is needed only to give a base case for the `Chain` instance resolution.

Comment: @phadej The `Control.DotDotDot` package doesn't do the same thing that I'm doing. It defines an operator that allows you to write functions like `\x y z -> g (f x y z)` as `g ... f` whereas you'd normally write it as `((g .) .) . f`. See: [What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/783743)

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed, the internal representation can simply be a function. I only created a GADT in order to stay faithful to the OP's original JavaScript code.