# How to create a Haskell data structure containing polyvariadic functions?

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions

How should I type and implement `run`, so that the following statements work ?

```
data Run = Run {run :: ??}

f1 = Run (\x -> x)
f2 = Run (\x y-> x+y)
f3 = Run (\x y z -> x*(y+z))

print $ run f1 1 :: Int --> 1
print $ run f2 1 2 :: Int --> 3
print $ run f3 1 2 3 :: Int -> 5
```

All the [polyvariadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467806/474491) in Run are of type Int -> ... -> Int: they take a variable number of Int arguments and yield a Int.

If it's any easier, I could live with a solution having a maximum number of arguments, e.g. 3:

```
data Run
  = Run1 (Int -> Int)
  | Run2 (Int -> Int -> Int)
  | Run3 (Int -> Int -> Int -> Int)

f1 = Run1 (\x -> x)
f2 = Run2 (\x y-> x+y)
f3 = Run3 (\x y z -> x*(y+z))
```

How would you implement `run` ?

Comment: What behaviour do you want on `run` being given the wrong number of arguments for a function? Some sort of run-time error?

Comment: Yes, a run-time error would be fine.  In practice, I'll use a recursive type class (i.e. with a base and a recursive definition) to feed it with the number of arguments it needs, e.g. from a random source.

Comment: I suspect [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544124/474491) could lead to the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `f1` and `f2` in your code have the same type `Run`, the type checker can not distinguish between `run f1` and `run f2` which must have the same type.

This makes it hard to implement variadic functions properly.

It's much easier to use instead

```
data Run a = Run { run :: a }
```

so that `f1` and `f2` no longer share the same type.

If you only care about functions `Int -> ... -> Int` there might be some solutions using type families, GADTs, DataKinds, and the like. This may be overkill, though, depending on what you are trying to realize.

Comment: I'm trying to realize the 3 print statements stated in the question...  Do you think you can do it with your suggestion ?

Comment: @user474491 it should work verbatim.  Give it a try!

Comment: Hey, you are right !  It's much simpler than I thought !  Many thanks.

Comment: However, I lose some flexibility in using Run.  For example, I cannot have a heterogeneous  list of Run, i.e. containing functions having different numbers of parameters.

Comment: @user474491 Correct. The problem is that a list is homogeneous, so in order to put all those functions in the list you need to lose the information about the arity.  Then, when you extract an element from the list, this is a "function with unknown arity" so `run (head list)` can not have a precise type. At best, we can have something like `run n (head list)` which will attempt to extract an n-ary function from the list, or fail at runtime if the length is not `n`.

Comment: `data Run a b = Run { run :: a -> b }` might be better, as it at least requires the wrapped value to be a function instead of any arbitrary type.